# Issue with two directives on the same model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote two directives. One of them is used for entering numbers with units (like "1m"):

```
angular.module('ng', [])
.directive('unit', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (s, e, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (i) {
                return i + attributes.unit;
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (i) {
                return (i + '').replace(attributes.unit, '');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The second one replaces `,` with `.`, because many people in Europe use a decimal comma instead of a decimal point and I want my values to be normalized.

```
angular.module('ng', [])
.directive('numberWithPoint', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (s, e, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (i) {
                return i.replace(',', '.');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The usage would be:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="howLongSomethingIs" unit="m" number-with-point /> m
```

The issue: the directive `unit` works great if it is alone, if I add the `number-with-point` directive, the `unit` takes no effect (the displayed value is for example `1m` not `1`.

I tried messing up with the `priority` property within the `return` object, but nothing happened.

How to make these two directives work together?

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3sf4ceL/), it seems to work, but it uses Angular 1.2.1. I am using Angular 1.3.14. Does somebody know how to make jsfiddle use other version?

Comment: Could you wire up a plunker/jsbin of the two directives? That'd surely help in debugging it.

Comment: Ok, good idea. Wait a sec

Comment: See edit. I added some comments

Comment: See my answer, just added a 1.3.14 fiddle - appears to be working there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been  found. An incredibly stupid thing. My directives were declared in two separate files, and each of them starting with:

```
angular.module('nameOfMyApp.directives', [])
```

Of course, loading a directive overwrites the `nameOfMyApp.directives` module each time.

I have changed it to

```
angular.module('nameOfMyApp.directives')
```

and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> In this jsfiddle, it seems to work, but it uses Angular 1.2.1. I am using Angular 1.3.14. Does somebody know how to make jsfiddle use other version?

I just ran the supplied code locally on Angular 1.3.15 - worked just fine.

Inputting `123071823,1238` evaluates to `123071823.1238m` when bound to the view. So it appears to be working just fine (on my end, and in your fiddle).

[1.3.14 jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw2fm4xp/)

---

Loading a different version on jsFiddle:

1. Remove angular from the `Frameworks & Extensions tab
2. Grab your version from [code.angularjs.org](http://code.angularjs.org).
3. Paste the link as an `External resource` in jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for testing... I kinda don't know what I am doing differently in my production code. It is actually almost as simple as the fiddle... Looks like I'd have to search deeper.

Comment: Myeah. I wish I could've been of more assistance here, but it does appear to be just working™.

Comment: See my answer... Well, actually you helped me - because if you haven't tested it with my Angular version, I would be still looking for the bug in the directive code and I wouldn't have came up with the right solution.

Comment: Ahh... yeah, I did not see that one in the original question. Sheesh. Glad you found it! :)